# Returning data in html(firebase & php - Firebase Admin SDK for PHP)

Tags: php, html, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm confused about the routing system in the Firebase Admin SDK for PHP, I want to display html pages, and have and direct users to different pages like like home, about, account, profile and ect but I don't know how to.

for instance, with laravel, you have your controllers, routes(web.php), and views(blade template) in your resources/views folder, all helping you to create html pages through blade templating

I have noticed something though, there are two predefined routes that already came with the project(git clone https://github.com/jeromegamez/firebase-php-examples), the urls for these routes are http://127.0.0.1:8000/users and http://127.0.0.1:8000/database, for instance, when I go to /users I get json data
[/users data in json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhy9I.png)

in a way this is out of context because I just want to have and be able to view html within this project(even if it returns no data from the database), but in the future i would like to retrieve similar data i showed on the image and place it on my html pages, through php, or even json to html however possible

the following is my project files structure
[project files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFyOL.png)

really hope you understand where i'm trying to go with this, your help will be appreciated

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: The SDK provided classes and methods to interact with the Firebase REST APIs, the examples repository is an example on how to integrate the SDK in a Symfony project and provides some examples for administrative tasks. The included routes and commands also just are examples. So, the examples project is not necessarily meant as a starting point for new projects - you can integrate the SDK in another Laravel or Symfony project as shown e.g. in https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/61#issuecomment-317985671